# CursorLoader Not Loading New Data When Underlying Database Replaced

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm hoping that somebody may be able to help me with something that I'm stuck on. I've searched StackOverflow looking at some other solutions and nothing is working so far.

I'm using a `ContentProvider`, `CursorLoader`, and `SQLiteOpenHelper` to get data out of a SQLite database into some ListViews. This has been working fine for a long time. I'm able to make updates, deletions, etc. to the data and the changes are reflected in the ListViews thanks to some use of `setNotificationUri` on the cursors and `ContentResolver`'s `notifyChange` function.

Recently, I've implemented a cloud backup feature for my app, where the database file is backed up to cloud storage for later retrieval. At this point, I run into problems.

I have no trouble bringing the database back down from the cloud and replacing the local database file with the inbound version. However, after doing this, my Cursors and Loaders continue to return data as it existed before the database file is replaced. If I exit the application and wait for its processes to end, then restart it, the new data then appears.

I know that Cursors and Loaders store data across the Activity lifecycle, so I believe this to be the source of my trouble, but any attempts I've made at invalidating this caching behaviour has failed.

What I've checked so far:

- Verified that `onCreateLoader` is in fact getting called after the database swap and the `CursorLoader` is getting recreated. It is.
- Verified that the new `Cursor` is getting swapped into my `CursorAdapter` via `swapCursor`. It is.
- Double-checked that I was using the correct URI values when I tried using `notifyChange`. URI values matched what I use when I update the data for a particular Listview for normal CRUD operations.

The only thing that has worked is to recreate my `SQLiteOpenHelper` object before every query, rather than relying on the instance created in my `ContentProvider` `onCreate` function. I assume though that this is bad practice and would create a scenario where too many connections are opened as I understand that every `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance manages its own connection.

Any help appreciated. Some relevant code snippets...

**DBHelper.java**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    ...

    public void ReplaceDatabase(Context c) throws IOException
    {
        // First, let's make sure the database is closed...
        this.close();

        File inboundFile = new File(c.getFilesDir(), this.INCOMING_DATABASE_NAME);

        if(!inboundFile.exists()) {
            throw new IOException("Incoming Database doesn't exist.");
        }

        File currentFile = c.getDatabasePath(this.DATABASE_NAME);

        if(!currentFile.exists()) {
            throw new IOException("Database doesn't exist.");
        }

        boolean deletionResult = c.deleteFile(this.BACKUP_DATABASE_NAME);

        try {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(currentFile);
            File backupFile = new File(c.getFilesDir(),this.BACKUP_DATABASE_NAME);

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(backupFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer))>0)
            {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw e;
        }

        try {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(inboundFile);

            currentFile.delete();

            File databaseFile = c.getDatabasePath(this.DATABASE_NAME);

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(databaseFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer))>0)
            {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw e;
        }


 c.getContentResolver().notifyChange(Asset.AssetTable.CONTENT_DETAIL_URI, null);

    }

}
```

**CoreProvider.java**

```
public class CoreProvider extends ContentProvider {
private DBHelper dbHelper;

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());

    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder){
    // Here I build the query. Then....
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = qb.query(
        db,            // The database to query
        projection,    // The columns to return from the query
        selection,     // The columns for the where clause
        selectionArgs, // The values for the where clause
        null,          // don't group the rows
        null,          // don't filter by row groups
        orderBy        // The sort order
    );
    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return c;
}
}
```

Comment: See [How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html#_unlinking_or_renaming_a_database_file_while_in_use).

Comment: @CL - I do reuse the name, although I don't have to. That can be changed. What I really need to get past though is the caching issue.

Comment: You must not delete or move the old database file as long as any connection might still be open.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @DANGERZONE94 No. I didn't.